# Same route but different template by device

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm in the situation where I need different templates to load for a specific device on the same route. Let's say for example a login page, is one route, but needs to load a different template for 3 devices (desktop, tablet, phone).
First step would be device detention, but then what would be the best or ember way of approaching this?

Media queries is not an option, because I don't want to shrink my desktop window and see tablet or phone layouts.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the browser detection on the server and serve up different template files depending on the device. Write your three sets of templates and compile them into separate Javascript files, then serve the correct Javascript file on page load. If you name and compile all of your templates the same way, Ember will never even know you have different templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can display a different template based on some condition by overwriting `renderTemplate` method inside your route. Here is an example of rendering a random template each time a route is accessed:

```
App.ThatRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    var random = Math.random();
    console.log(random);

    if(random > .5){
      this.render('template1');  
    }
    else {
      this.render('template2');
    }   
  }
});
```

Working on jsbin [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hekezu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)